# Parse cisco asa config

Tags: configuration, cisco

Has anybody come across a utility or devised a procedure to identify redundant objects etc within asa config (cisco asa 5520) or any firewall.  I am currently searching via notepad ++ for objects to identify if they are being used.

I want it identify duplicate / overlapping access lists, service groups, network object groups, redundant IP names etc.

What I am trying to achieve is a nice neat and tight firewall config.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loaded config into notepad ++.
Searched for each object and deleted if required

Painful but it works :(